# How to change default Shortcuts in MacOS

Tags: macos, shortcut

How to bind "quit application" to something other than Command + Q?

I cannot find a place in the shortcut menu where I can set a new bind for "quit (current) app".

Comment: It's Command/Q & it's universal, but why on earth would you want to?

Comment: Console doesn't really use key commands much, do you mean some Terminal derivative? I'm still not seeing why you want to break the entire ecosystem for an alt key. What happens if you want to type œ ? onomatopœia is no longer available to you ;-) But seriously, why? I honestly don't understand the need.

Comment: You could change swap those modifier keys and see if you are habitual of alt c alt v for copy paste.

Comment: @personanongrata I have set cmd+ escape for specific apps where I accidentally press q instead of w,1,2,3 etc. (use @ to ping people )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, it is ‘Command + Q’ and not Alt + Q.

You can install a free utility named ‘Karabiner’ to map your ‘different’ key strokes to quit the apps and Command + Q to something else.