# Prevent Atom quitting on Cmd-Q

Tags: keyboard

I used to rebind <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> to invert colors to prevent quitting from programs, but it seems that after Catalina it keeps reverting to quitting after reboot (and it likes rebooting a ton). Is there an alternative? I have <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> in Atom to close tabs, now I constantly accidentally close my editor.

Comment: As a general rule I'd strongly suggest that one not change ubiquitous system wide keyboard shortcuts such as **⌘Q** and find a different alternative to whatever the issue is. That said, are you changing it globally of just for Atom?

Comment: I am changing it globally through keyboard shortcuts. It keeps reverting :(

Comment: Have you tried just changing it for Atom, and if yes, does it not hold the binding after a reboot too?

Comment: Unfoirtunately not all Apps use Apple's UI infrastructure, Atom is one and so it will not follow some macOS behaviours

Answer (score 2):

System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts tabs → App Shortcuts. Use + button to add new shortcut and enter exactly what "Quit Atom" menu item says in atom app. I use <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>escape</kbd> for Safari, VSCode and Xcode where I accidentally press <kbd>Q</kbd> instead of tab, w, 1, 2, 3 etc. and it's been great so far.  I've been using it for ~3 months now.

Both global and application defined shortcuts work.  Unique menu item is the key.

I am on Mojave.

[image]

Comment: 1. Are you running **macOS Catalina**? 2. Do these settings sustain a reboot? 3. Why are you setting **Quit Visual Studio Code** and **Quit Xcode** as _global_ vs. _application_?

Comment: **1** It slipped my mind while clicking the post button to mention Mojave. **2** yes, I've been using it for ~3 months now. **3** I don't remember why I did that in the past, but both work. Unique menu item is the key. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/368296/how-to-change-default-shortcuts-in-macos#comment493136_368296 this is the state of mind in which I answered this.

Comment: The OP is using **macOS Catalina** and said settings were not persisting a reboot when set globally, however I've just now tested with some default apps and Atom; it works with **⌘⎋**, as you show both globally and per application, in **macOS Catalina** (10.15.1) too. While the OP is using a different binding, nonetheless +1 for a proven method.

Comment: Yes! Same technique I recommend for [avoiding accidental ⌘-Q quits of Safari](https://alanhogan.com/tips/reduce-accidental-safari-quits)

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite Atom's internal keybinding:

- open Atom settings (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>)
- open **Keybindings**
- click "your keymap file"
- your `keymap.cson` will open in a new tab, enter the following

```
'body':
  'cmd-q': 'unset!'
```